# Android jsoup Error 500

Tags: javascript, android, jsoup

Before I go into this please do not mark as a duplicate, because as you will see there is some more going on here than a regular error.
I am trying to parse a specific div class out of a really simple webpage. Whenever I try to run it, I get this error `org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=500, URL=http://newenglandophthalmic.com/`
This is the code I currently have to pull the `div` class:

```
private class VersionCheck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    String URL1 = "http://newenglandophthalmic.com";
    String stringVersion;
    int convertedString;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(UpdateActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Checking Current Version Number");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.show();


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            connection = Jsoup.connect(URL1).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; rk3118 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Safari/537.36").timeout(10000);
            resp = connection.execute();
            doc = null;
            if(resp.statusCode() == 200){
                doc = connection.get();
                Log.d("DATA", doc.toString());
            }else if(resp.statusCode()==500){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error 500", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
       progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Some common suggestions/solutions that I have tried/investigated:

- Your internet speed is too slow.

It isn't. My device can load the webpage in approximately 3-5 seconds in a browser window.

- Your connection must be timing out too quickly

I obviously increased the timeout time to 10000

- Try ignoring `http` errors

Tried, didn't work at all. Android monitor printed the same error.

- Maybe you are having trouble compiling the `json.jar`

No, my gradle file adequately imports and includes the `json.jar`

- Maybe you should change your url from `http://newenglandophthalmic.com` to `http://www.newenglandophthalmic.com`

Tried, no dice. 
 - CLEAN/REBUILD your project

Once again, nothing. 
**NOTE** The site is being hosted by GoDaddy.com, not sure if this has something to do with it.

Does anybody have any other ideas on what I can try?

Thanks a ton everybody!

Comment: I think you have an extra 'n' in *String URL1 = "http://new**n**englandophthalmic.com*".

Comment: I did, that was my mistake in writing the post, the actual `URL1` in the program is correct, though.

Comment: I've just tried your code on my PC, got response = 200 and everythung looks OK.

Comment: @TDG I think it has something to do with my operating system on the device. For some reason it couldn't parse GoDaddy hosted pages, but could parse other pages perfectly fine. Strange.